# How to return specific field in Elastic Search-PHP[1.0] client

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using `Elasticsearch-PHP [1.0] client` (link below):

> [1]: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_quickstart.html

I want to return specific fields from elastic search..I have written the following code :

```
$params['body']['fields'] = ["title","prod_desc"];
```

but it's not working..Please Help..

Comment: What you mean by not working? It doesn't return anything, or returns whole document anyway?

Comment: doesn't return anything...

Comment: Make sure, that these fields are stored in index (`store: true` in mapping).

Comment: when i'm executing the above query in terminal using curl call then query runs..but not in php..

Comment: Then I think you should post both working query and full PHP code of not working query. If not you have to compare them on your own.